# Remove duplicated records periodically in Sql Server/Compact Edition

Tags: sql-server, xml, ssis, entity-framework-5

I need to remove duplicated records, as a maintenance task, inside the sql server instance or in my local compact edition testing database. 
 Because, I have a tool that reads a clock device that outputs workers check-in/out workday. I export reading data to Xml files as a backup and insert the objects parsed into the database. 
So, there are to many records for insertion daily and I will like to do it in a optimal manner without having to check other values existing in the database every time I need to insert.

What recommendation you give me?

I'm using Entity Framework 6

Do I deal with EF and Linq for managing duplicates and SqlBulkCopy?
Do I create temporary tables in Sql Server?
Do I create a Sql store procedure that does so?
Do I use SSIS (I'm a newbie on that) for importing Xml files?

### I have two tables:

-Clock (Id, Name, Location)
-Stamp (Id, ClockId, WorkerId, StartDate, EndDate, **State**)

**State**: Evaluation of worker assistance attending to Start/End (in a normal work day: *8.00am-5.00pm*).

-BadStart
-BadEnd
-Critical (Start/End out of admisible range)
-Pending (Those who not yet has been processed and normalized)

### How do I process data:

There are **2 clocks units** (each creates its own stamps, but workers can check-in/out in any of them)

-Read clock data from the device (other application does that, the physical machine has a scheduled task that runs a script that reads the clock unit device. Output: Xml files)
-Parse Xml files (*Compatibility issue:* Human Resources department has other application that reads it in that specific format)
-**Insert/update records in database according to some normalizing rules**
As you could see, the table can't have unique fields, because the same worker can check-in/out several times (by mistake, by confirmation, by other clock) and all these stamps has to be unified/normalized for the day in course.
*The duplicates are created each time I run the parser that reads all Xml files in the directory and insert them in the database.*
I don't have permissions to modify the physical machine directory hierarchy.
So I'm looking a better strategy for clasify, store and remove redundant records.

The task should be performed daily and several Xml files are created from each clock unit in a specific directory. The clock is connected via a serial wire to a physical machine.

Comment: How do you define duplicate records? What is your table structure?

Comment: What do you mean by mirror tables? How are the duplicates getting in there in the first place? Does it make sense to prevent it from getting in? If you're only interested in doing a periodic cleanup, store procedure is probably your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your preference and data model, there are several ways to skin this cat.

See the following links that have examples. Most of them use `CTE` - Common Table Expression. You should be easily able to adapt it to your needs, and then schedule the script to run as a  SQL Server Job periodically.

1) [Different strategies for removing duplicate records in SQL Server.](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1918/different-strategies-for-removing-duplicate-records-in-sql-server/)
2) [Using CTE to remove duplicate records](http://www.mssqlgirl.com/using-cte-to-remove-duplicate-records.html)